# With multiple audio players in React, pause all but currently playing player

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio, setstate

I have a Playlist component that is importing *n* number of `<AudioPlayer />` components dependent on how many tracks are in the playlist.

What I need to do is pause all other `<AudioPlayer />` components except the one that is currently playing. Otherwise, you can play multiple players at once which is no bueno.

In my Playlist component, I'm able to grab both the currently playing player as well as the 'not playing' players: when a player is played, it fires the `onPlay()` handler which grabs the refs of all of the currently mounted players, then I compare that to the playlist and finally, extract the players that are currently **not** playing.

What I'm stuck in is updating the state of the players so that when I press play on a different player, all of the other players are paused.

The `<AudioPlayer />` components have a `prop` of `playing` which I should be able to use to pass down the updated playing state when a new player is played.

How can I do this?

Here is my `Playlist.js` code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import AudioPlayer from 'react-cl-audio-player'

const streamUrl = 'https://mystreamurl.com/'
const waveUrl = 'https://mywaveformurl.com/waveforms/'

class Playlist extends Component {
    state = {
        playlist: this.props.tracks,
        playing: false,
        currentPlayer: '',
        notPlaying: []
    }

    onPlay = (refName, index) => {
        // Get list of AudioPlayer components from refs
        const players = Object.keys(this.refs).map((key, i) => {
            return this.refs[key]
        })

        if (players) {
            // get AudioPlayer that is playing
            const currentPlayer = players[index]

            // get playlist items that are not playing
            const notPlaying = this.state.playlist.filter(
                (track, trackIndex) => {
                    return trackIndex !== index
                }
            )

            // Compare playlist items that are not playing to AudioPlayer list
            // to find AudioPlayer components that are not playing
            var notPlayingPlayers = players.filter(function(obj) {
                return notPlaying.some(function(obj2) {
                    return obj.props.alt == obj2.track_audio
                })
            })

            console.log('Not Playing Players', notPlayingPlayers)
            // ^^ this gets me the <AudioPlayer /> components that arent playing

            const notPlayingPause = notPlayingPlayers.map((item, x) => {
                this.setState({
                    playing: false // I know this isn't correct.
                })
            })
        }
    }

    render() {
        const tracks = this.props.tracks
        const sku = this.props.sku
        const price = this.props.price
        const addToCart = this.props.addToCart

        const trackList = tracks.map((track, index) => {
            const songs = [
                {
                    url: `${streamUrl}${track.track_audio}_128.mp3`,
                    cover: '',
                    artist: {
                        name: ' ',
                        song: track.track_title
                    }
                }
            ]
            return (
                <li
                    key={sku + '-' + track.track_audio}
                    className="playlist-track"
                >
                    <span className="playlist-name">{track.track_title}</span>

                    <AudioPlayer
                        key={track.track_audio}
                        index={index}
                        songs={songs}
                        autoplay={false}
                        src={`${waveUrl}${track.track_audio}.png`}
                        alt={track.track_audio}
                        ref={track.track_audio + index}
                        onPlay={this.onPlay.bind(this, 'player', index)}
                        playing={this.state.playing}
                    />

                    <span className="playlist-price">$1.99</span>
                    <button
                        type="button"
                        className="button playlist-button"
                        onClick={() => {
                            addToCart({
                                product_id: track.track_product_id,
                                quantity: 1,
                                price: price,
                                cart_item_data: {
                                    name: track.track_title
                                }
                            })
                        }}
                    >
                        Add To Cart
                    </button>
                </li>
            )
        })
        return (
            <div className="playlist-wrap">
                <ul className="playlist">{trackList}</ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Playlist
```

Here's an image if it helps to make it more clear:

[image]

Comment: Why not just render a single `AudioPlayer` and make it play the currently selected track? A `Playlist` component should not render a `Player`. Instead there should be a parent component that renders both a player and a playlist and passes the currently selected track from the playlist component to the player component as a prop.

Comment: @trixn the reason I am not doing it that way is that each track needs it's own progress slider which is placed over a waveform image of the track. To have individual progress sliders I need multiple `AudioPlayer` components as they are part of the component.

Comment: I know it's been 3 years @joshuaiz , but have you figured this out? 

Comment: @antonwilhelm I have! I created my own React audio component that handles playing only one track at a time here: https://github.com/joshuaiz/reaudio